# absolute difference on a relative scale

Tags: statistics

I have two sets of four data points where I check the absolute differences. I also want to show the relative difference, but I face some issues here.

Currently I use the formula:

$$\frac{x-x_{ref}}{x_{ref}}$$

The issue with this formula is that the large numbers can show a smaller deviation than the smaller numbers, where the deviations can be quite high. For example: the difference between two larger values, like 14.4 and 23.8 is around 40%, while the difference between 0.35 and 0.49 (in the same set) is around 29%. It can be seen that the difference in the smaller values is less significant as compared to the larger values, but the relative difference is rather high. Hence, the formula here is more sensitive for smaller values than higher values.

I found a post on this from around 10 years ago ([How to compute the relative difference between two numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500723/how-to-compute-the-relative-difference-between-two-numbers)), where this is handled with the following formula:

$$\left ( \frac{\left |x-x_{ref}  \right |}{x_{ref}} \right )\left( 1-exp\left ( \frac{\left |x-x_{ref}  \right |}{a} \right ) \right )*100\%$$

Where `a` is set to `100` in the case stated in the post.

My question is how to handle this. The formula stated in the linked post seems to do the job, but I find it a unclear what value for `a` I should use. On another note, I am not sure if a different formula has emerged during the last 10 years for this issue.